# ERROR: No matching distribution found for open3d==0.15.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 31))

Tags: python, containers, requirements, open3d

I am doing a docker container to install CLIP-Fields (https://github.com/notmahi/clip-fields).

The requirements.txt can be seen in the github. I am trying to install them, but when I get to open3d, the following error appears:

```
#0 16.26 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d==0.15.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 31)) (from versions: 0.10.0.0, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.12.0, 0.13.0)
#0 16.26 ERROR: No matching distribution found for open3d==0.15.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 31))
```

The Dockerfile I created is:

```
# Use the official PyTorch base image with CUDA support
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.8.1-cuda11.1-cudnn8-runtime

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

# Clone the CLIP Fields repository
RUN git clone https://github.com/notmahi/clip-fields /clip-fields
WORKDIR /clip-fields

# Clone and install the Detic submodule
RUN git clone https://github.com/notmahi/Detic.git

# Clone and install the LSeg submodule
RUN git clone https://github.com/notmahi/LSeg.git

# Create a conda environment and activate it. py 3.8 used
RUN conda create -n cf python=3.7 && \ 
    echo "conda activate cf" >> ~/.bashrc
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

# Install dependencies
RUN conda install -y pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch-lts -c nvidia
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
# Set the working directory to the gridencoder folder
WORKDIR /clip-fields/gridencoder

# Install the hashgrid encoder with the relevant CUDA module
# Update the CUDA_HOME path if necessary
ENV CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
RUN python setup.py install

# Set the working directory back to the root of the CLIP Fields repository
WORKDIR /clip-fields

# Run any necessary commands or scripts here

# Set the command to run when the container starts
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Why is the error appearing? open3d 0.15.2 does exist! :( (https://pypi.org/project/open3d/#history)

Answer (score 0):

I added "RUN pip install --upgrade pip" to the Dockerfile, and updated pip and now it istalls open3d 0.15.2. BUt why do i need to upgrade it in Dockerfile everytime?